# HOney Comb Android emulator not responding

Tags: android, emulation, android-3.0-honeycomb

Android Honey Comb 3.0 is not responding  properly to the Application launch coomand ... any workaround on that

Comment: try to launch a hello world app.. if it works, there may be some problem with your app.

Comment: I have the same problem on 3.1, it's just weird.